# " java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found" error due to data source

Tags: java, oracle

I have installed oracle 11g into my system. I have created my own data source using **ODBC Data Sources** in **control panel**. Details are given as shown in the image below :

[image]

I was trying to trying to access this data source through my java code :

**JdbcType1Test.java**

```java
package connectionTests;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class JdbcType1Test {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException {

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:nithin_ds","system","manager");

        System.out.println(con);

    }

}
```

After executing the above program I am getting errors like this:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:odbc:nithin_ds
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at connectionTests.JdbcType1Test.main(JdbcType1Test.java:13)
```

Comment: try `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");`

Comment: i have changed , still getting same exception

Comment: Java no longer has support for ODBC (and that support was always pretty buggy). If you want to connect to Oracle, you need to use the Oracle JDBC driver **and** the correct JDBC url for Oracle. Your current URL isn't valid.

Comment: read this https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/connect-to-oracle-db-via-jdbc-driver-java/

Comment: Since I am working in eclipse, the project where I have this code has ojdbc14.jar in its classpath ... i have used  `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");` in other codes also ... they are working fine

Comment: i know there is mistake with url and that is due to **nithin_ds** data source. so in control panel i have cross checked by clicking **test connection** .  As a response i got **connection successful** message. Still I cannot make out  what is wrong with my url

Comment: Valid connection URL for JDBC for Oracle looks like this:
`jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOST:PORT/SERVICE_NAME` or `jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOST:PORT:SID`

Comment: Yea thats true but I was following a video tutorial which was using the url pattern mentioned in the problem ... it was working fine.